# Как избежать множественного включения?

Tags: c++

Можно ли создать объект класса внутри другого класса не подключая заголовочный файл в header с описанием этого класса. сумбурно. Но вот пример.

Обычно я делаю так.

```
//a.h
class A
{
public:
    A();
};
```

```
//a.cpp
#include "a.h"

A::A()
{

}
```

```
//b.h
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B();

    ~B();
    A* a;
};
```

```
//b.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

B::B()
{
   a = new A;
}

B::~B()
{
    delete a;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <a.h> // Все ок
#include <b.h> // никаких конфликтов

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Предварительно объявляю класс A. Создаю указатель на него в классе B, таким образом, если мне нужно подключить заголовки с этими классами к одному файлу, все ок. Но все же, можно ли создать не указатель на объект A. А объект этого класса, внутри класса B. Может есть что то эдакое. Или по крайней мере как не следить за этим объектом, если не при помощи умных указателей. Если известно, что объект класса А будет существовать на всем протяжении жизни объекта класса B.

Comment: Где создать в `main` или член `B` объявить не указателем?

Comment: @Cerbo второе.  Сей час Поле A* a; Хотелось бы A a;  дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Чтобы создать объект класса внутри другого класса этот класс должен быть определен, соответственно необходимо подключать заголовочный файл.

Comment: мне кажется тут нужна `#pragma once` или `#ifndef define`. Если я правильно понял вопрос конечно

Comment: @WierdGreenCat Какую проблему решаете?

Comment: в файле  //b.h класс  A не имеет ничего общего с классом  в  //a.h

Comment: @VTT но ведь указатель я создать могу. Почему бы не создавать объект класса А в конструкторе. Но не объявлять его как указатель. Звучит бредово, да, не спорю.

Comment: Для объявления указателей, ссылок, а также аргументов функций (то бишь когда поля и методы класса без разницы) достаточно только предварительного объявления класса.

Comment: @WierdGreenCat А почему вы не хотите просто подключить нужный хедер?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я думаю, просто чего то не понимаю, со всеми этими включениями и изобретаю велосипед, решая несуществующую проблему.
С чем я сталкивался. Например создание глобальной переменной, которая будет видна в большом количестве единиц трансляции. (Это решается синглтоном) Автоматическое удаление полей класса. (За указателями приходится следить) Иногда их слишком много и я точно не знаю, какие уже были удалены, а какие еще живы.( это решают умные указатели, либо просто оборачиванием в другой класс)  И еще куча мелких ошибок, которые я получаю. Я просто думал нет ли общего решения.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нет нельзя. Без указателей или ссылок или умных указателей не обойтись. Вообще.

Объявление типа нужно компилятору, в том числе, и для того, чтобы определить размер этого объекты в байтах, чтобы создавать объекты этого типа. Размер указателя компилятору известен, он всегда один и тот же и не зависит от типа. Поэтому чтобы создать объект `B` не нужно знать размер `A`. Если же объявить что поле `B::a` не указатель, а сам объект `A`, и не привести определение `A`, то размер `B` невозможно будет вычислить. И будет ошибка компиляции.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятору в заголовке нужно вычислить размер класса. Если у тебя, как сейчас, указатель, он понимает, что это 4/8 байт и доволен. Сам класс A ему понадобится уже в cpp файле и включать его можно уже там. Если вы создаёте не указатель, а объект, то заголовку `B` нужно знать размер `A`. `А` при этом нужно включать уже в .h файле.
Но ничего страшного в этом нет. Кроме весьма особых случаев, в которых преследуется цель сократить время компиляции, включать, например, заголовок a.h в b.h вполне нормально. Для избежания множественного включения стоит в начале каждого .h файла писать `#pragma once` и компилятор сам всё разрулит.